# Python logging formatter on different levels

Tags: python, logging, formatter

How can I use different format on different levels of python logger?
For example, I want INFO:root disabled for INFO level, but still showing up for warning.
Currently I have this code:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S -')
```

Which does: "Time - Message" for all levels. Can I maintain that format for INFO only, and still remain at default for others?